# Troubleshooting Cooling System Problem

Tags: troubleshooting, cooling-system

I Own a Mahindra 4*4 Pickup truck , Its running at high temperature.

I have changed the following:

1. Radiator
2. Temperature sensor
3. Water pump
4. Hoses pipe
5. Coolant

Please could you help me resolve the prblem.

Comment: Hello Vijeandra, welcome on this site.
A small suggestion:
1. Please do not write everything in uppercase, this is considered screaming.
2. Please explain detailed: The symptoms, measured already undertaken and additional observations

Comment: Under what conditions does the vehicle overheat?

Answer (score 4):

The first two things you want to do is establish that the vehicle is actually running hot and that the coolant system is healthy.  It may be something as simple as the gauge on your dashboard misreporting temperature.  One good way to do this is the switch on the cabin heating.  If it's very hot, it's fair to say that the vehicle is running hot.

With the system COLD, check that the vehicle has the correct amount of coolant.  If it's low, top it up.  Do this with the heater control set on "Hot" and be sure to squeeze the radiator hoses to make sure no air is trapped in the system.  Once you are happy that the coolant level is correct, before you refit the cap, start the engine.  Look at the coolant, does it look like it's circulating?  Again squeeze any air out of the radiator pipes.  After the vehicle has been started, stop it and check the coolant level hasn't dropped.  If it has, add coolant and repeat.  If you find that the coolant level drops after a few days use, you may have a leak somewhere on the system.

If you find that the vehicle gets hot when stationary, it may be that the radiator fan isn't effectively cooling the raditor.  There are two types of fan; electric and mechanical.  The electric fans rely on wiring and for testing, you can bridge the wires and the fan should run.  For the mechanical system, there is a thermostatic clutch which runs the fan when it warms up.  This can fail meaning the fan doesn't spin as quickly as it ought to.

If the gauge is working, the coolant is circulating, not leaking and the fan is healthy; check the condition of the radiator.  If it has damage, is missing fins or is blocked with debris, it won't be able to effectively transfer the heat away from the system.  A quick blast of the fins with a hose (whilst cold) is usually enough to dislodge any debris.

If none of this has worked (and assuming your other levels such as oil are not low) it may be time to have a compression test carried out to establish the health of your cars head gasket.  If you don't have access to a compression tester, your local mechanic shouldn't charge you much to carry this out.  Also, check for signs of coolant entering the oil system.  If you find white, creamy deposits inside the oil cap, this is an indicator that the coolant and oil have been mixing.  In a vehicle equipped with a water-oil oil cooler this can be the cause but it usually indicates a loss of integrity of the head gasket.

Good luck.